# Send HTML in some array over AJAX but fail to display it, not well-structured

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cpanel

I want to add print a web page function and it works well in localhost but when I upload it into real-server the result was not well-structured.

I've js function that get specific html content and pass it into

```
var cetak = (function() {
return function() {
    judulTabel = $('#judul_tabel').text();
    nTabel_hasil = $('.tabel_hasil').length;
    jqLeftHeader = [];
    jqInnerDivLeft =  [];
    jqRightHeader = [];
    jqInnerDivRight = [];
    tabel_hasil = [4];

    for (n = 0; n < nTabel_hasil; n++) {
        def = ".tabel_hasil:nth-of-type(" + (n + 1) + ")";
        n1 = def + ' #jqLeftHeader';
        n2 = def + ' #jqInnerDivLeft';
        n3 = def + ' #jqRightHeader';
        n4 = def + ' #jqInnerDivRight';
        jqLeftHeader[n] = $(n1).html();
        jqLeftHeader[n] = $(n1).html();
        jqInnerDivLeft[n] = $(n2).html();
        jqRightHeader[n] = $(n3).html();
        jqInnerDivRight[n] = $(n4).html();
    }

    tabel_hasil[0] = jqLeftHeader;
    tabel_hasil[1] = jqInnerDivLeft;
    tabel_hasil[2] = jqRightHeader;
    tabel_hasil[3] = jqInnerDivRight;

    $.post("cetak.php", {
        "judulTabel": judulTabel,
        "tabel_hasil": tabel_hasil,
        "kirim": true
    }, function(data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            console.log(data);
            window.open("cetak.php", '_blank');
        } else {
            console.log('lho');
        }
    });
 };
})();
```

Below is cetak.php

```
<?php include 'receivePost.php'?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {        
    if (confirm("Apakah Anda akan mencetak tabel ?") === true)
    {
        window.print();
        window.close();
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

});
</script>
```

And below is receivePost.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['kirim'])) {
    $_SESSION['judulTabel'] = $_POST['judulTabel'];
    $_SESSION['tabel_hasil'] = $_POST['tabel_hasil'];
} else {        
    $content = '<html><head></head><body>';
    $content .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">' .
                '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modOutput.css">'.
                '<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>';
    $tabel_hasil = $_SESSION['tabel_hasil'];
    $nTabel_hasil = count($tabel_hasil[0]);    

    for ($n = 0; $n < $nTabel_hasil; $n++) {
        $content .= '<table id="tabel_hasil" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >' .
                    '<tr>' .
                        '<td>'.
                            $tabel_hasil[0][$n].
                        '</td>' .
                        '<td>'.
                            $tabel_hasil[2][$n].
                        '</td>' .
                    '</tr>' .
                    '<tr>' .
                        '<td>'.
                            $tabel_hasil[1][$n].
                        '</td>' .
                        '<td>'.
                            $tabel_hasil[3][$n].
                        '</td>' .
                    '</tr>' .
                '</table>'.
            '<br/>';
    }
    $content .= '</body></html>';
 }

 echo $content;
```

And the output is here

```
<table id=\"tableLeftUp\">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style=\"background-color: rgb(0, 33, 66); color: white; min-width: 200px; height: 89px;\" id=\"th2b\" rowspan=\"4\">Propinsi</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How I can remove the '\' character? Are there any modification in my code so I can avoid not well-structured html when displayed?

Regards

Comment: `striplashes()` in your php code

Comment: In my case after striplashes added, single qupte character appear and I use str_replace to replace it. Thanks T100rk